# Evans PDE p.714 Change of variable and change of integration region

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes

In the following definition of convolution involving mollification . 
When I make change of variable $x-y=z$, I have
$$\int_{U}\eta_{\epsilon}(x-y)f(y)dy=\int_{?}\eta_{\epsilon}(z)f(x-z)dz=\int_{?}\eta_{\epsilon}(y)f(x-y)dy,$$ why does the integration change from $U$ to $B(0,\epsilon)$?

[image]

Hope to receive a comprehensive detailed explanation from anyone. (Preferably in a geometric way...I come across long time ago, but I really couldn't find those scribbles...hope someone could help drawing some pictures...two or three circles perhaps, in my memory)

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\eta$ is supported in the unit ball $\overline{B(0,1)}$, i.e. $\eta(x) = 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^N \setminus \overline{B(0,1)}$. Again by definition, $$\eta_{\epsilon}(x) = \epsilon^{-N}\eta(x\epsilon^{-1}).\tag 1$$

Now I claim that $\eta_{\epsilon}(x) = 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^N \setminus \overline{B(0,\epsilon)}$. Indeed, fix such a $x$, notice that $x\epsilon^{-1} \in \mathbb{R}^N \setminus \overline{B(0,1)}$ and use $(1)$ to prove the claim.

This implies that $\eta_{\epsilon}(x - y) = 0$ for $y \in \mathbb{R}^N \setminus \overline{B(x,\epsilon)}$. Moreover, if $x \in U_{\epsilon}$ then $B(x,\epsilon) \subset U$. Then we have

$$
\int_U\eta_{\epsilon}(x - y)f(y)\,dy = \int_{B(x,\epsilon)}\eta_{\epsilon}(x - y)f(y)\,dy.
$$

Now it should be much easier to understand how the domain of integration changes with the change of coordinates $z = x - y$.

Comment: it would be even nicer if there is a picture along your explanation:)

Comment: I am sorry but, a picture of what exactly? the change of variables is a rigid translation, so the domain is not stretched in any way.

Comment: I was thinking about $U_{\epsilon}$, $U$ and a circle with radius $\epsilon$.

Comment: I see: $U_{\epsilon}$ is the set of point with distance at least $\epsilon$ from $\partial U$. If you want to sketch this draw the set $U$ first and then draw a "smaller" $U$ inside maintaining a constant distance from the boundary. This is nothing but a technicality to ensure that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset U$. Indeed, if $x$ is allowed to get too close to the boundary then obviously the ball need not be contained in $U$.

Comment: I can draw the picture, but I still cannot see how the equality holds, I mean the second equality you have above. Thanks for your explanation I am trying myself now...

Comment: it is all about trying to understand things in a unknown bigger space by things in a known smaller space pictorially, by verifying the equivalence of the areas.

Comment: All the work before the second equality was done to show that $\eta_{\epsilon}(x - y)$, and hence the integrand, is $0$ outside $B(x,\epsilon)$, hence the integral over $U \setminus B(x,\epsilon)$ is $0$. I hope this clarifies :)

Comment: what does $\overline{B(0,1)}$ mean? I think you mean Unit ball includes boundary (i.e. closed unit ball).

Comment: It refers to the closure. Notice that I call it "unit ball" in the first line of my answer

Comment: Ok. Also, I do not understand elements in $\mathbb{R}^N \setminus \overline{B(0,1)}$ are approximated by $\frac{x}{\epsilon}$. What is the intuition here...

Comment: Nothing is being approximated. The fact you mentioned can be restated as follows: if the norm of $x$ is larger than $\epsilon$, then the norm of $x/\epsilon$ is larger than $1$.